# complement of open set over which a birational morphism has an isomorphism has at least codimension 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ be a birational, proper morphism and $X$ a proper variety. Let $W\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be the maximal open set such that $f$ is an isomorphism over $W$.
Why is codim$(\mathbb{P}^n\backslash W)\ge2$?

I know that this is true for a maximal open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$, such that $U\rightarrow Y$ is a representative of the rational map $\mathbb{P}^n\rightarrow X$, because:

If $P\in \mathbb{P}^n$ is a point of codim(1), then $\mathcal{O}_{P,\mathbb{P}^n}$ is a discrete valuation ring (because $\mathbb{P}^n$ is normal) and $X$ proper it follows from the valuative criterion of properness the map Spec$(k(\mathbb{P}^n))\rightarrow X$ extends to a map Spec$(\mathcal{O}_{P,\mathbb{P}^n})\rightarrow X$. Therefore $\exists V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ open and $P\in V$, such that $V\rightarrow X$ is a morphism. So $P\in U$ and codim$(\mathbb{P}^n\backslash U)\ge 2$.

Is $f$ an isomorphism over $U$?
(If $f$ is an isomorphism over $U$: $U\subseteq W$, so codim$(\mathbb{P}^n\backslash W)\ge 2$).

Comment: Your claim of discrete valuation is correct only under some hypothesis on $X$.

Comment: @Mohan I'm not sure what you mean. I try to follow the proof of Lemma 3.2 in https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/AVs.pdf

Comment: I thought because $\mathbb{P}^n$ is normal I have a discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_{P,\mathbb{P}^n}$.

Comment: This question seems to have been answered before https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1481426/801393

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rational map is not defined on a subset of codimension $\geq 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481426/rational-map-is-not-defined-on-a-subset-of-codimension-geq-2)

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Thank you, but I understand that codim $(\mathbb{P}^n\backslash U)\ge 2$ but why is codim $(\mathbb{P}^n\backslash W)\ge 2$?